# Using AWK to delete line and output result

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a text file and manage to find the line through output comparison. 
With the book title and author name.

```
awk -F ':' '/KungFu Feet|Chuck Norris/'  test.txt

Kungfu Feet:Chuck Norris:12:1:1
```

Is there any way to delete the line using `awk` and return the output in a bash file?

**EDIT**

I would like to do a check for the following item before i do the deleting using awk

```
  If (( Book = KungFu Feet  && Author = Chuck Norris )); do
    echo "Item is found unable to delete" 
  else 
    echo "Deleting.."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a need to do this with `awk`, you might want to try something with `grep` and `sed`:

```sh
if grep -E "(KungFu Feet|Chuck Norris)" your_file ; then
    # fancy stuff in case string has been matched
    sed -r "/(KungFu Feet|Chuck Norris)/d" < your_file > new_file
else
    # fancy stuff in case it hasn't
fi
```

If you need POSIX `sed` compatibility, you'll have to expand the regex for `sed` (`grep` in recent POSIX versions supports the `-E` option):

```
sed -r "/KungFu Feet/d;/Chuck Norris/d" < your_file > new_file
```

Some version of `sed` also allow in-place changes through the `-i` option.

Re-reading the answer, you would probably need to match just `"KungFu Feet:Chuck Norris"` in both `sed` and `grep`. This is of course thanks to the extremely simple format of your data.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do what you want:

```
$ awk -F ':' '!/KungFu Feet|Chuck Norris/'  test.txt | tee newtest.txt
KungFa Feet|Chuck Narris:12:1:1
KungFe Feet|Chuck Nerris:12:1:1
```

#### New file

```
$ cat newtest.txt 
KungFa Feet|Chuck Narris:12:1:1
KungFe Feet|Chuck Nerris:12:1:1
```

Comment: Thanks alot. but i would like to output a if else statement with echo so "if ( $Book = "KungFu Feet" &&  $Author = "Chuck Norris"  ) echo Item found deleting using awk else Item not found.

Comment: @LennonChia - can I ask why? Not being wise, I'm generally curious as to why you want that over what I posted. I'm wondering if there is more to your ultimate goals with your question too.

Comment: it work thanks alot for being so helpful but i would like to do a check on my shell script before i do the awk delete. so when the user enter the book and the author there will be a check before i do a awk delete. I am still stuck trying to figure out how to do it using bash. But i am hoping to learn to use awk  too. I am sorry if i may be giving the wrong impression i am still trying to learn some of the bash basic , awk and sed function.

Comment: @LennonChia - my example doesn't do a `awk` delete, just creates a 2nd file.

Comment: i can rename the file so it alright and delete the old file :)

Comment: @LennonChia - yeah that's what I would do too 8-). Also take a look at these examples using `if` in `awk`. You can do `if ($1 == "KungFu Feet" && $2 == "Chuck Norris") ..`. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/